# How to find a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for the splitting field of $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the splitting field of $x^{4}-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{K}\leq \mathbb{C}$ a field extension. Determine a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{K}$.

First, denote $f(x)=x^{4}-2$, I've already shown that the spliting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{2}i)$ and is indeed a degree 8 extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, I'm having trouble determining a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{K}$.

I believe $(1,\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{4})$ would be a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$, but that's all I've gotten so far. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: When you say $\sqrt[4]{2i}$, do you mean $\sqrt[4]2i$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, my mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting field of $x^{4 }-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543210/splitting-field-of-x4-3-over-mathbbq)

Comment: If $K$ is a degree-8 extension of $\Bbb Q$, then it is an 8-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$; how many elements must a basis have? (This is different from elements that generate $K$ as a field extension—$\sqrt[4]2$ and $\sqrt[4]2i$ do this, but that's a different question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to make use of the following theorem (which proves the degree formula for field extensions):

> Let $F\le E\le K$ be finite extensions.
> Let $\{\alpha_i\in E: 1\le i\le n\}$ be an $F$-basis for $E$
> and $\{\beta_j\in K: 1\le j\le m\}$ be a $E$-basis for $K$.
> Then $\{\alpha_i\beta_j:1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le m\}$
> is an $F$-basis for $K$.

First, let's fix some mistakes.
The set $\{1,2^{1/4},4^{1/4}\}$ is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$.
We know that $x^4-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/4}$,
so any basis must have $4$ elements.
In fact, one such basis is $\{1,2^{1/4},2^{1/2},2^{3/4}\}$.

Let $\mathbb{E}:=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$.
It remains to find a $\mathbb{E}$-basis for $\mathbb{K}$.
Note that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},i)=\mathbb{E}(i)$.
We know that $x^2+1$ remains irreducible over $\mathbb{E}$ (because the roots of $x^2+1$ are non-real, but $\mathbb{E}\subset\mathbb{R}$).
Then $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{E}$,
so $\{1,i\}$ is a $\mathbb{E}$-basis for $\mathbb{K}$.

By the quoted theorem,
we then have that $\{1,2^{1/4},2^{1/2},2^{3/4}, i, 2^{1/4}i,2^{1/2}i,2^{3/4}i\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{K}$.